# Change Unity wallpaper in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04, desktop-background

In previous Ubuntu releases, the user was able to modify the Unity wallpaper  in the System Settings programme (Appearance panel). This action no longer has an effect on Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

How can I change the Unity wallpaper in this Ubuntu release?

**Update I**: this is the output [requested by Joshua Besneatte](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066145/change-unity-wallpaper-in-ubuntu-18-04#comment1746906_1066145):

```
$ pstree -s $(pidof X)|grep gdm
        |-gdm3-+-gdm-session-wor-+-gdm-wayland-ses-+-gnome-session-b-+-gnome-shell-+-Xwayland---14*[{Xwayland}]
        |      |                 |                 `-2*[{gdm-wayland-ses}]
        |      |                 `-2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
        |      |-gdm-session-wor-+-gdm-x-session-+-Xorg---3*[{Xorg}]
        |      |                 |               `-2*[{gdm-x-session}]
        |      |                 `-2*[{gdm-session-wor}]
        |      `-2*[{gdm3}]
```

**Update II**: following some discussions on Google+ I tried [disabling Wayland](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). This had no effect, though.

**Update III**: [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172093/change-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-custom-photo-in-ubuntu-18-04) was opened in September of 2019. Please mark that other as duplicate, not this one.

Comment: Have you installed and logged into Unity manually (18.04 has GNOME by default)?

Comment: Unity was installed automatically.

Comment: it should be gdm... what happens if you run this `pstree -s $(pidof X)|grep gdm
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change desktop wallpaper to a custom photo in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172093/change-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-custom-photo-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling desktop icons in Gnome Tweaks helped me with this issue.

[image: gnome tweaks show icons switch]

In case you don't have Gnome Tweaks:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```