# Change desktop wallpaper to a custom photo in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, customization, desktop-background

How to change the desktop wallpaper to a photo of my own selection in Ubuntu 18.04? I'm not interested in downloading some wallpaper changer application, nor am I interested in coding something up. There has to be an easy way to select a photo as a custom wallpaper in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98498/discussion-on-question-by-jarett-lloyd-change-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-custom-phot).

Answer (score 7):

#### 20.04

*Settings* → *Background* → click a wallpaper to select it or *Add Picture* (optional).

#### 18.04

1. Open the Settings application by clicking on its icon that has a gear with a red wrench over it.
2. From Settings select the Background category and click on the Background image.

   [image: Background]
3. Download a new wallpaper .png format image to your Pictures folder or copy an existing .png image that you want to use as a wallpaper to your Pictures folder. In the below screenshot the first three images are wallpaper images that were already downloaded to my Pictures folder. Look for an image that will look sharp and crisp if it is used for a desktop wallpaper.
4. Select the *Pictures* tab and click on any image to select it as the new wallpaper. The selected image will be surrounded by an orange border when it is clicked.

   [image: select a new wallpaper]
5. Click the green Select button to select the image that is surrounded by an orange border as the new wallpaper.

Comment: is there a way to add a custom ... folder/tab to this?  what if i have a collection of pictures on a completely separate drive...?

Comment: One easy way to do it is to copy your collection of pictures from the separate drive into your Pictures folder. Another way to do it is to right-click any image and select *Set As Wallpaper*.

Comment: i have the pictures stored on a NAS and would rather not copy some 10,000 images over...

Comment: @JarettLloyd This request deserves to be asked as a separate question.

Comment: you might be right about that.

Comment: Notice that if you "add a picture" it will be copied to your local install. So when adding 10.000 images you'll end up with 10.000 copies on your local disk.